# How do multiple formats in DateTime.TryParseExact work?

Tags: c#

I have a system which processes a bunch of file names and the names contain timestamp. My system finds out whether the file is older than a configured number of days. I get the files from a completely different system that I have no control over.

I'm converting the timestamp into DateTime through this code,

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(match.Value, "yyyyMMddhhmmssFFFFFF", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out timestamp)
```

My issue is the timestamp I get from the other system is sometimes 12 hr clock format and sometimes 24 hr clock format. I cannot get them to use a single format. So in the end I've decided to use the multiple formats overload available for TryParseExact like this,

```
string[] formats = new string[2] { "yyyyMMddhhmmssFFFFFF", "yyyyMMddHHmmssFFFFFF" };
        DateTime.TryParseExact(match.Value, formats, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out timestamp);
```

My question is will this affect how the output DateTime is, which format will get applied first? Will this cause any disruption in the logic where I calculate whether the file is older than configured number of days. The following is my logic to find out if the file is older,

```
timestamp.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(configuredDays)) < DateTime.UtcNow
```

Comment: [They are visited in turn](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs#L207-L225).

Comment: The 12-hour format should have an am/pm indicator or it might be 12 hours off.

Comment: Obvious question - how can you possibly recover the correct time when using `hh` and no `t`? Given that lack, why not treat them both as just 24 hour?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever doesn't the "ss" and "FFFFFF" specifiers handle the time?

Comment: `t` is the meridiem - such as `AM` or `PM`.

Comment: Understood. I have to find out if the other system which is Java based, send the "t" specifier if their time is configured for 12 hr.